# How do I sort a table alphabetically and numerically in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, vue.js

I'm currently working on sorting functionality on a table built with vue.js. I have ascending sorting currently working with numbers. However I am unable to get the descending and alphabetical functionality to work properly.

Here is my html where I am calling the sort functionality. Currently I have this as a method().

```
     <tr class="dash-table-mainHead">
              <th 
                v-for="(column, key) in columns"
                :key="key"
                @click="sortTable(column)"
              >{{ column.label }}</th>
            </tr>
```

Here is the javascript where I have my array of columns with appropriate fields.

```
  data() {
        return {
            columns: [
                { label: this.$t('reporting.source'), field: 'source' },
                { label: this.$t('reporting.accountsWithActivity'), field: 'accountsWithActivity', align: 'center', type: 'icon' },
                { label: this.$t('reporting.answerableConversations'), field: 'answerableConversations', type: 'boolean', align: 'center' },
                { label: this.$t('reporting.interactiveConversations'), field: 'interactiveConversations', type: 'boolean', align: 'center' },
                { label: this.$t('reporting.leads'), field: 'leads', align: 'center' },
                { label: this.$t('reporting.interactiveLeadConversations'), field: 'leads', type: 'date' },
                { field: 'blank' },
            ],

            convertedData: [],
            // currentSort: 'name',
            currentSortDir: 'asc',

        }
    },
```

And finally my method where I am doing the sorting. This currently works for ascending only and doesn't appear to be sorting alphabetically.

```
methods: { sortTable(column) {
            console.log(column.field)
            let sortedData = [];

            sortedData = this.convertedData.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a[column.field] < b[column.field]) { return -1; }
                if (a[column.field] > b[column.field]) { return 1; }
                return 0;
            })
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a computed property `sortedData` for your items and put that in your template instead of `convertedData`
2. If comparing strings, use `String.localCompare`.
3. Add a `sortField` data property.
4. Simply set the `sortField` to null or your clicked field value to make the magic happen.

```
@click="sortField=column.field"
```

```js
let component = {
  data() {
    return {
      // convertedData: ...
      sortField: null,
      currentSortDir = 'asc'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sortedData() {
      if (this.sortField === null) {
        return this.convertedData;
      }
      return this.convertedData.sort((a, b) => {
        let res;
        if (typeof a[this.sortField] === 'string') {
          res = a[this.sortField].localeCompare(b[this.sortField])
        } else {
          res = a[this.sortField] > b[this.sortField] ? 1 :
            a[this.sortField] < b[this.sortField] ? -1 : 0
        }
        if (this.currentSortDir !== 'asc') {
          ret = ret * -1;
        }
        return ret
      })
    }
  }
}
```

If you have `null/undefined` values you will have to do some more work checking the types.

It is now very easy to sort multiple fields.  And the sort direction can be reactive as well by just updating the sort direction data property.

Comment: We will need more code posted then.  You do not show where your computed data comes from, or where your template loops the data.